# Sending exception back to client thrown by a flume sink

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, flume-ng

I am planning to use Flume with HTTPSource to upload data to HDFS. The sink will be configured to save data to Hive/Hbase table. If there is any excpetion/error writing data to HDFS, can it be thrown back to the client?
HTTPSourceHandler throws exception if it is unable to parse the data or if unable to send data to memory channel, but can an exception thrown by a sink be sent back to client?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, sources work as data producers and sinks as data consumers. This means the sinks will not put any data into the channel, and the sources will not get any data from the channel. Nevertheless, I think you can create (never tested, just figuring out how to do such a thing) custom sources and sinks that work both as sources and sinks; in that case you could have 2 channels, one for each direction, and perform some kind of back communication.

In any case, if you are expecting to send back Http responses about all the possible errors regarding the workflow from the source to the sink, I would say you to forget about that: once the data has been put into the channel by the source, there is no guarantee such a data is inmediately process by the sink; it could take 1 second or 1 minute to be processed (the channel, which behaves as a queue, may have a lot of previous data). I mean, you do not want to implement that kind of synchronous communications because the new data arriving to the Flume agent will have to wait a lot.